# product customization with extra price in magento

Tags: magento, customization, custom-attributes

I am using Magento for my online store. Now i need to add a extra feature, throught which, customer can choose a custom text that needs to be engraved on the product. This feature must be available for only few products, so i have added a yes/no dropdown custom attribute in the "manage product" section. If yes is chosen for a product, i need to show a text box in that product details page in the store frontend.

The customer can enter the custom text in the text box, which needs to be saved and shown in the order invoice. And a extra fixed charge needs to be added to the product price, when this feature is used by the customer.

Does any community module available for this feature in magento or Do i need to create a custom module to do this, if so please guide me in carrying this out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is already available.

1. Create a new product!
2. Open the **Custom Options Tab**
3. Add a custom option
4. Give your new option a **title** and select **field** as input type
5. Now the attributes for this new options get displayed
6. Add a fixed or percent price to it
7. Also you need a SKU for every new option so that the options are displayed in the order process (invoice etc)
8. Done

So if a customer fill in this field the additional price is added automatically.

I hope this helps further.

[image: Custom Options]

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a yes/no box, just add an text field option to those specific products. Did i miss something obvious here?